# What does the % value indicate in method suggestion in eclipse neon

Tags: eclipse-neon

When we type in some method or when we do ctrl+k in eclipse neon IDE, it provide method name suggestion. In the suggestion i can see some % value which are in descending order.

What does this % mean? Is it realted to method performance or word releavence or something else.

[image: Suggestion_Box]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is related to word relevance. The percentage (EX. %96) is meant to show you the  nearest relevant code and the percentage that it will be related to what you have typed.

Comment: So it comes up on the line when you type?

Comment: it comes when your object is appended with "."

Comment: Yeah, it i trying to suggest potential syntax. It will disappear if you type a proper command. (That the coding program recognizes of course).